# angular ui-grid : change label of the sum aggregate

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I am using the sum aggregate to calculate some totals in an angular ui-grid.

The totals get displayed just fine but I could not figure out how to change the label that gets preceeds to the total.

if the total is 5000 for example, the footer will display : total : 5000

How do I remove the word total ? I see it in the source but I cannot figure out how to change it without changing the source.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the 'undocumented' (http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/api/ui.grid.class:GridOptions.columnDef) property that can be used for this purpose : aggregationLabel

Answer (score 2):

you can remove that just bu adding this function

```
$scope.hideAgregationChar = function( aggregation ){
    aggregation.rendered = aggregation.value;
    };
```

and in your grid definition add this

```
customTreeAggregationFinalizerFn: $scope.hideAgregationChar,
```

or if you wan to change the word to another one just change the cell templates like this

```
cellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">\'Total\' (capital \'T\') {{col.getAggregationValue() | number:2 }}</div>'
```

that will change the total to Total for example.

Answer (score 0):

You have to include just `footerCellTemplate` as below for that particular column which you need to aggregate `sum`.

```
    footerCellTemplate: '<div class="ui-grid-cell-contents">\Total:\ {{col.getAggregationValue() | number:2 }}</div>'
```

for example, the above line will change the total to Total.